# URL not opening correctly on another browser asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, url-routing

I have an asp.net mvc application were i send sms messages with URL to clients. message and URL is sent correctly but when i click on the link it does not open correctly, example there is no data passed from database, example if you click the following url, there is no data passed to view: http://binvoicing.com/InvoiceAddlines/PaymentPreview?originalId=11&total=585.00

Here code:

```
  public ActionResult SendSms(string cellnumber, int? id, string rt, string tenant, decimal? total, string userloggedin)
    {
        StreamReader objReader;
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        int payid = 0;
        int paypalaid = 0;
        string UrL = "";

        string pass = "mypassword";
        //string cell = cellnumber;
        string user = "username";


        var pay = from e in db.PayfastGateways
                  where e.userId == userloggedin
                  select e;

        var paya = pay.ToList();


        foreach (var y in paya)
        {
            payid = y.ID;

        }


        var pal = from e in db.PaypalGateways
                  where e.userId == userloggedin
                  select e;

        var payla = pal.ToList();


        foreach (var y in payla)
        {
            paypalaid = y.ID;

        }


        string url = Url.Action("PaymentPreview", "InvoiceAddlines", new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { originalId = id, total = total }), "http", Request.Url.Host);

        if (payid == 0 && paypalaid == 0)
        {
            UrL = "";

        }

        else
        {
            UrL = url;
        }
        string mess = " Dear Customer, please click on the following link to view generated invoice, you can also pay your invoice online." + UrL;

        string message = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(mess, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));

        string baseurl =
          "http://bulksms.2way.co.za/eapi/submission/send_sms/2/2.0?" +
          "username=" + user + "&" +
          "password=" + pass + "&" +
          "message=" + message + "&" +
          "msisdn=" + cellnumber;

        WebRequest wrGETURL;
        wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(baseurl);

        HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://www.vcskicks.com/c#");
        try
        {
            Stream objStream;
            objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);
            objReader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }

        ViewBag.cellnumber = cellnumber;
        ViewBag.id = id;
        ViewBag.rt = rt;
        ViewBag.tenant = tenant;
        ViewBag.total = total;
        ViewBag.UrL = UrL;


        return View();
    }
```

SMS send url like http://binvoicing.com/InvoiceAddlines/PaymentPreview?originalId=11&total=585.00

Here Is my PaymentPreview method:

```
   public ActionResult PaymentPreview(int? originalId, decimal? total)
    {
        TempData["keyEditId"] = originalId;
        ViewBag.ind = originalId;


        decimal totals = 0;


        totals = (decimal)total;


        var line = from e in db.InvoiceAddlines
                   where e.AddlineID == originalId
                   select e;

        var addlines = line.ToList();
        foreach (var y in addlines)
        {
            decimal? de = Math.Round(totals);
            string tots = de.ToString();
            y.Total = tots;

            db.SaveChanges();

        }


        return View(db.InvoiceAddlines.ToList());
    }
```

Hope someone can assist, thanks.

Comment: You have shown us your `SendSms()` method which you claim is working, but you have not shown us the `PaymentReview` method and view which is not working.

Comment: Thanks Stephen Muecke, i have just included PaymentReview method.

Comment: when you debug into it what do you have in the parameters originalId , total ?

Comment: And what is the view? We cannot guess what your issue is or what you are expecting the view to display (and why are you calling the database again instead of just using `return View(addlines);?)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with the way URL is being built. See if this works -

Change this part of your code

```
string url = Url.Action("PaymentPreview", "InvoiceAddlines", new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { originalId = id, total = total }), "http", Request.Url.Host);
```

To

```
string url = Url.Action("PaymentPreview", "InvoiceAddlines", new { originalId = id, total = total })
```